# Accurately getting subdomain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

I have a running app that needs to get the subdomain and I use:

```
var requestHost = context.Request.Url.Host;
var subdomain = requestHost.Split('.')[0];
```

Now, this works most every time, but every once in a while (and has been happening MUCH more frequently recently, it instead returns the start of the IP address "137" or "www" or for some unknown reason "customer". Recently, it's started to happen all the time, until I recycle the Application Pool in IIS. Then it works again.

I am totally clueless. Is this something with a setting in IIS? How does it work most times but not EVERY time? For reference, I'm running an ASP.NET webforms 4.0 web app on IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) within an Azure VM. Could it be something Azure related?

Comment: your method should work as long as somebody goes to url without `www` like `http://domain.example.com`, but you will have an issue once the user enters `http://www.domain.example.com`

Comment: Yes, that is true, but that doesn't explain the errors for the IP address showing through or why I've seen the errors when I hit the site correctly.

Comment: Do you have "Host name" set on you IIS binding? It might be a red herring but I'm wandering if it's possible that your website is called with some internal address instead of full domain.

Comment: I don't think so, it should allow all subdomains through. Where do I check for that?